# How to keep track of which mouse buttons are pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to detect which mouse buttons are pressed in a mousemove handler.

At first it seemed pretty easy, I tried this:

```
function mouseMove(event) {
    switch (event.buttons) {
        ...
    }            
}
```

This worked fine until I tested on Safari. Unfortunately, Safari doesn't suppport MouseEvent.buttons.

So then I tried to keep track of the mouse button states manually, something like this:

```
let isRightMouseButtonPressed = false;

function mouseDown(event) {        
    if (event.button === 2) {
        isRightMouseButtonPressed = true;
    }
}

function mouseUp(event) {        
    if (event.button === 2) {
        isRightMouseButtonPressed = false;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
```

The problem with this approach is that if the context menu is shown after mousedown, and the button is released while the context menu is visible, then mouseup isn't raised.

A possible solution might be to set isRightMouseButtonPressed = false in a contextmenu event handler. But sometimes other contextmenu handlers are invoked which disable the context menu by calling `event.preventDefault()`. I can't find a way to detect whether the context menu is actually shown.

So, any of the following would be helpful:

- A polyfill that adds support for MouseEvent.buttons on Safari
- A way to detect when the context menu is actually shown (not just when the contextmenu event is raised)
- Some other way to detect which mouse buttons are pressed during mousemove

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7122

Comment: Just as a note, Safari supports this as of Safari 11 (released March 28, 2018).